# Explaining structural v. reduced-form

Tags: structural-estimation, teaching, reduced-form-estimation

Consider your audience is Econ 101 students.

You want to explain structural models and reduced-form models as easily as possible.

What prime examples (e.g., seminal paper reference) would you give to them to explain these two terminologies?

I am looking an example like the one in Hayashi gives in his econometrics book (Ch. 3.1) where he talks about the simultaneity bias with a system of demand and supply equations to explain "endogeneity".

Comment: Hi @Frank. I understand your point regarding simplification, but the audience will never be Econ 101. Therefore, I wondered if you could clear up something you believe to be missing in Hayashi's treatment or something that you believe would be missing from this treatment?https://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/s14/312/notes/Notes10.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are that many econometrics papers that accessible to Econ 101 who do not have any prior statistics background.

Rather I would point students to good econometrics textbook. For example, Wooldridge, Introduction to Modern Econometrics in ch 15 has several very good and clear examples of structural and reduced form equations. All examples in Wooldridge are actually based on literature (you can check the references in the chapter), however, Wooldridge masterfully simplifies them for the student.

When I teach econometrics 101 I always use examples from the Wooldridge, even when the official textbook for the course differs. I might be biased since it was the textbook I was taught during undergraduate, but ever since I used several various econometrics textbooks and I simply find Wooldridge to be the most clear and concise.

My advice is to simply pick one or more examples from Wooldridge, and then you can add papers based on which they are made as a part of reading list for interested student.

Comment: this is a great reference. I will take a look at the Wooldrige reference.